# Convert Gamma/RGB curves to RGB curves with no gamma

Tags: image-processing

With softwares like GIMP and Photoshop, it is possible to apply RGB curves, but the function is using an extra "gamma" curve.

When programming and manipulating pixels, I often only own 24 bits, RGB only frames, so it is impossible to directly use RGB curves created/detected in a 3rd party imaging software and re-use them to hardcode some arrays like this in a program:

```
byte[] rCurve = { ... }
byte[] gCurve = { ... }
byte[] bCurve = { ... }
```

How does this 4th, gamma curve acts on the red, green and blue curves? It increases or decreases all of them?

[Edit]

Doing a quick check, first thing I notice is that it acts like a multiplier on colors, maximizing them when raising it, minimizing them when decreasing it. i.e. The image only has tones, and no more brightness level if I maximize the gamma curve. I wonder what is the exact calculation to re-create it on my 3 pixel arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gamma is just an attempt to correct the non-linear nature of the monitor to achieve a linear brightness "curve". To apply gamma there is no need to hard-code anything.

Simply multiply each component with the gamma value like this:

```
gamma = 1 / 2.2
r = 255 * pow(r / 255, gamma) // pow(value, power)
g = 255 * pow(g / 255, gamma)
b = 255 * pow(b / 255, gamma)
```

To reverse it back from linear to gamma you can do this:

```
gamma = 2.2
r = 255 * pow(r / 255, gamma)
g = 255 * pow(g / 255, gamma)
b = 255 * pow(b / 255, gamma)
```

2.2 being default for Windows (1.8 for Mac)

[image]

Comment: Either I'm wrong about how I named this 4th curve, or I don't know how this adjustment algorithm can be applied linearly, from 0 to 255. I'll check these software functions deeper. I guess it's still a gamma curve. Thanks!